# Apache & Tomcat reverse proxy with basic authentication: Can Tomcat receive the username?

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I've successfully configured Apache to listen over SSL/443 and proxy Tomcat listening on HTTP/8080.  I have also set up basic authentication in Apache.

Once the user connects to my Tomcat servlet, will the HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() be populated or null.  If null, how might I get the remote user?

Comment: Are you using `mod_proxy` or `mod_proxy_ajp`?

Comment: @larsks I'm using mod_proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution may be to use `mod_proxy_ajp`, which in addition to proxying requests also transfers a variety of metadata to Tomcat, including authentication information such as `REMOTE_USER`.

[These docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/config-modproxyajp.html) for Alfresco discuss this configuration, which includes changes on both the Tomcat side (so that it knows to trust the forwarded authentication) and the Apache side.

If you're using a generic http proxy like `mod_proxy`, you would need to arrange for Apache to add the value of `REMOTE_USER` to the request (possibly as an `X-` header), and then arrange for your Tomcat application to recognize and trust that header (and you would obviously need to arrange for your front-end proxy to *strip* that header from any incoming requests).

I don't know how you would do this on the tomcat side, but [this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/215082) seems to have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
</Location>
```

to the wrapping location, the RequestHeader being the specialty that fixed it.

I found this (again) via http://codeblow.com/questions/remove-fundamental-authentication-header-with-apache-mod-proxy/ - don't know where I originally found it last year, it was a last measure for some security issue.